# Why can't I sell my plants?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I'm playing plants vs. zombies on the iPhone and don't have the facility to sell my plants. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean in the Zen Garden?

Answer (score 4):

You can't sell plants, only dig them up once you have the shovel